# Ajax response gets me the whole html page

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to get a number from an ajax request. I first tried it in a few simple files (and it worked perfectly) but now I want to do it on my website, and instead of having a number as a response, I seem to have an html page that has nothing do to with what I want to get. Here's my code :

In articleView.php :

```
<div id="boutonLike" onclick="like(<?php echo $idArticle; ?>, <?php echo $_SESSION['idUtilisateur']; ?>)"> LIKE </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  function like(idArticle, user) {
    $.ajax({
      url : '../Controllers/LikeController.php',
      type : 'GET',
      data : 'idArticle=' + idArticle + '&user=' + user,
      dataType : 'text',
      success : function(result) {
        //$('#boutonLike').text(result);
        alert(result);
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  }

  </script>
```

In LikeController I just did :

```
<?php echo 2; ?>
```

And it seems that when I get the result I somehow get the html code of my website instead of the "2" that I want to get.

I am a beginner and I don't know much about Ajax, and I've searched for like days, now I really don't know what to do...

Thanks for helping me and reading this

Comment: If you try to load LikeController directly in your browser what does it do then?

Comment: I have a router I guess that was part of the problem. Now I do in my router :
case 'ok' :       require_once('../Controllers/LikeController.php');
                       break;

And in Ajax request I do : url : 'ok'

But now I just get nothing as a result of my ajax request